# HTML5 Pattern for FULLNAME

Tags: regex, html

I'm trying to validating a form submit just if, in just ONE field, the user enters his First Name and Last Name.

I know: in other countries, it's not like this, but I'm doing for Brazil, so its First Name and Last Name.

What I have tried:

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" pattern="^.* .*$">
```

But it didn't work.

The field needs a First name (minimum 2 characters, no limit), a SPACE, then the last name with minimum 1 characters and no limit too.

Examples:

TRUE:

João da Silva

João S

João S.

Joao S. Pedro

FALSE:

Joao

João

Joao  (just a space)

I hope you can understand me.

Thank you so much.

---

Actual code: does not work any validation:

```
<form action="http://xxxxxxxxx" method="POST">

* Nome Completo: <input type="text" name="fullname" required="required" pattern="^(\w\w+)\s(\w+)$" /><br>

* Telefone: <input type="tel" name="mobilephone"/><br>

* E-Mail: <input type="email" name="emailaddress1"><br>

* Informe melhor horário para contato: <input type="text" name="crmcol_sugestaodecontato"><br>

<input type="hidden" name="crmcol_novocontato" value="64340000"><br>

<input type="hidden" name="crmcol_origemdoregistro" value="643400005"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar" class= "botaoenvio" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Enviando, aguarde um momento..';this.form.submit();">
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern looks for 2 or more "word characters", a single space, then 1 or more following word-characters:

```
pattern="^(\w\w+)\s(\w+)$"
```

The automatic client-side validation using `pattern=""` won't happen unless the `input` is inside a `<form>`, you should also add the `required` boolean attribute too to avoid empty (but valid) input.

I've made a JSFiddle demonstrating it here: https://jsfiddle.net/3r4Luwnp/

#### Update:

I created a JSFiddle with your updated markup and it looks like your custom script in your `onclick` handler calls `form.submit()` directly, this will skip client-side input validation.

If you change the button to `<button type="submit">` and remove the `onclick` JavaScript then it works fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/rpkn31d6/

Comment: I just insert this pattern and write "q" on form, its going normal without a validation.

Comment: @MarkG. There was a typo in my `pattern=""` that I've fixed. I've also added other instructions.

Comment: @MarkG. Please don't use comments for posting code, please update your original question instead.

Comment: Done it. I'm sorry.

Comment: @MarkG. I've updated my answer. Please see the JSFiddle link I posted.

Comment: Yea. It really worked. 

But im still need to disable / hide the button after the first click. Every script will skip the client-side?

Comment: Buddy, you can help me with this: In Brazil, some names have "~" or "´"

Like: João, André. When i put this name on the field, the pattern blocks this name. What should i put to fix this?

Comment: Can you help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: for anyone having issues in rails with this (as i have been) - in the form helpers, you need to escape the escapes (\) so the above becomes: <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "name", class: "form-control",pattern: "^(\\w\\w+)\\s(\\w+)$", title: "We need your full (first and last) name so that our partner Hotels can recognise your bookings.", required: true %>